# Bundle registration for jquery maskedinput not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

**What am I doing wrong?......**

I'm registering the [jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) in a bundle script the exact same way I'm registering several other scripts but for some reason the bundle for this script simple doesn't work...

#### I have tried with the following Bundle registrations SAME RESULTS:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-{version}.js"
    ));
```

---

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"
    ));
```

---

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"
    ));
```

---

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-{version}.min.js"
    ));
```

---

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"
    ));
```

#### This is the rendered HTML

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery.maskedinput?v=" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**But my bundle is empty**

#### This is my registration on my `MasterPage`

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js"  Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/bundles/jquery.validation" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/bundles/jquery.maskedinput" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>

    </Scripts>
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

#### This is a screenshot of my scripts in Visual Studio 2012

[image]

What's going on?? I just don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the 1.0 RTM version which will ignore *.min.js even if explicitly included in debug mode.  If you update to 1.1.0-alpha1 package, this should be fixed.

Alternatively you can work around this issue using the answer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087527/minified-script-only-in-mvc4-bundleconfig).