# Minified script only in MVC4 BundleConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, asp.net-optimization

I am adding the following ScriptBundle in BundleConfig:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/javascript").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*",
        "~/Scripts/load-image.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.*",
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-image-gallery.*",
        "~/Scripts/my.global.js"));
```

This is referenced at the end of my _Layout.cshtml as:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/javascript")
```

When debugging I notice that the output of this script rendering is:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-image-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/my.global.js"></script>
```

Notice the load-image.min.js script is missing? What I want is to use that same minified script whether I'm debugging or not. Under release conditions the script is included in the bundled JS file.

I assume it's seeing the 'min', looking for an un-minified version, not finding one, then deciding what's best is to ignore it entirely. Brilliant. If I make a copy of load-image.min.js, call it load-image.js and then reference it in BundleConfig as "load-image.*" I find it is included in both configurations but what's the point of having to do that?

I assume I'm missing something here. I don't have the un-minified version and I frankly don't care about it. It's used by my Bootstrap image gallery plugin and nothing else. Any ideas out there?

Comment: +1 for `then deciding what's best is to ignore it entirely. Brilliant.` That happens way to often :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior has been improved (fixed) in the 1.1.0-alpha1 release.  We moved all of the old default ignore list entries into a new DirectoryFilter ignore list that are only used when including search patterns like *.js which was the origional intent for this functionality.  As a result this should no longer be an issue when you are including individual files explicitly.

Note: the one place this might still be an issue is if you try to include something like jquery-{version}.min.js.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How can we get over this? What software version are you referring (1.1.0-alpha1)?
Can you please show an example on how one can explicitly include a file (eg `test.min.js`) when the non-minified is missing.

Answer (score 5):

There is `ignoreList`, which you can clear if you need, it looks like:

```
public static void AddDefaultIgnorePatterns(IgnoreList ignoreList)
{
    if (ignoreList != null)
    {
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.intellisense.js");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.debug.js", OptimizationMode.WhenEnabled);
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.js", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
        ignoreList.Ignore("*.min.css", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ignoreList");
    }
}
```

More details: [Advanced Options of ASP.NET Bundling and Minification](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/09/30/hidden-options-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @webdeveloper - a quick glance at this would indicate that to achieve what I want I would need to clear this ignore list entirely and re-populate with explicit file names. Obviously I'd like to retain the ability to ignore minified files in development, but with this one explicit exception. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: @tomtroughton This list works by mask, no need to type explicit file names. Also you can use `#ifdef DEBUG` to write some logic only for debug.

Comment: you could set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to enable minification in debug mode, so he wouldnt ignore the .min files, but I guess this isnt exactly, what you intended to do, cause the whole bundle will be minified and hard to debug.